# SP 2013 List Validation: enforce sequential dates

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, list-validation

I'm having formula and logic trouble getting a list validation formula that will force the user to enter four dates in sequential order. I have Date1, Date2, Date3, and Date4. I also need to skip a calculation if a "later" date is blank.

I would be grateful for help. Thanks-

Comment: Could you provide example for "skip calculation"? Are these valid entries: [09/22/2020, 09/23/2020, Blank, 09/24/2020]; [09/23/2020, Blank, 09/24/2020, Blank]?

Comment: Hi Matiur. 
I am sorry for the confusion. I need the validation to only work (for example) on Date2 when Date1 has a date, or on Date3 when Date2 has a date. So, if the previous date field has a data value, the most recently filled date in the sequence gets the validation.
Thank you!

Comment: posted my answer. Let me know your feedback or if you have any questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following formula and see if that works.

```
=IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(Date1)),NOT(ISBLANK(Date2))),IF(DATEDIF(Date1,Date2,"D")=1,IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(Date2)),NOT(ISBLANK(Date3))),IF(DATEDIF(Date2,Date3,"D")=1,IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(Date3)),NOT(ISBLANK(Date4))),IF(DATEDIF(Date3,Date4,"D")=1,TRUE,FALSE),TRUE),FALSE),IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(Date3)),NOT(ISBLANK(Date4))),IF(DATEDIF(Date3,Date4,"D")=1,TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)),FALSE),IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(Date2)),NOT(ISBLANK(Date3))),IF(DATEDIF(Date2,Date3,"D")=1,IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(Date3)),NOT(ISBLANK(Date4))),IF(DATEDIF(Date3,Date4,"D")=1,TRUE,FALSE),TRUE),FALSE),IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(Date3)),NOT(ISBLANK(Date4))),IF(DATEDIF(Date3,Date4,"D")=1,TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)))
```

**Screenshot showing valid entries**

[image]

Comment: Hi Matiur: The good news is that The validation wondows accepts the code you wrote so that great! The bad news is I'm getting a "Exception from HRESULT: 0xE0040035".  I am checking it with our admins but nonetheless, thank you so much. This is brilliant!

Comment: Hope this works out for you. Only thing I've noticed is that you might see a syntax error when [end-date] is < [start_date] in DATEDIF(start_date,end_date,unit). But this still stops user from submitting the form. Let me know if you have any questions or need any explanation of the formula.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to achieve your requirement by list validation.